# Help Identifying this bass

Tags: electric-bass-guitar

I found this (Vision) bass real cheap, and grabbed it just because I couldn't seem to find anything online , found a guitar that looked identical but nothing as far as a bass, I think its japan made bass guessing from maybe 70's 80's ? probably pretty cheap but any info would be great [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpv90.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I think it’s a Vision bass.

Comment: Yes I am looking for any info on it though as I cant find anything online like when was made ect....

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think your vision regarding the visibility of that Vision bass's _Vision_ logo is quite visionary. I tip my visor, wouldn't have seen that even vis-à-vis with the visigoth who envisioned the design.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - well, it's sure not a Tele...

Comment: lets all remember that @darrin is *new* and might take your joshing personally? He can probably read the word Vision.

Comment: Not taken personal LOL just looking for more info then just the obvious name is all

Comment: Identification of instrument types vs. specific instruments (brand, model) is currently being discussed on meta: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/do-we-still-agree-that-identification-of-types-of-instrument-is-on-topic-should?cb=1

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's a Vision VB200 from the mid 1980s (the pointy headstock decade).  They used to be made in Japan, like all Vision instruments.  I can't find a photograph online, but you can see a tiny image here: 
[image]

The headstock is the exact same shape as [THIS](https://www.gettyimages.ae/detail/news-photo/guitar-manufactured-by-vision-with-white-body-and-neck-and-news-photo/90761551) guitar from 1990, and [this](http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/vision-vs200-guitar/4889) VS200 guitar from 1986.

Comment: Thanks that is some good info, I had found the guitar that looked just like the bass but never anything on the bass at all but goes to make send as they look identical

Comment: Glad I could help !